# Renaming columns in a list of dataframes?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, rename

I have a list of DataFrames that look like this,

`dfs`

```
 [                   
    var1       var1  
 14.171250  13.593813
 13.578317  13.595329
 10.301850  13.580139
 9.930217   13.593278
 6.192517   13.561943
 7.738100   13.565149
 6.197983   13.572509,                  
   var1       var2    
 2.456183  5.907528
 5.052017  5.955731
 5.960000  5.972480
 8.039317  5.984608
 7.559217  5.985348
 6.933633  5.979438
 ...
 ]
```

I want to rename `var1` and `var2` in each DataFrame to be `Foo` and `Hoo`. 
I [tried](https://chrisalbon.com/python/pandas_rename_multiple_columns.html) the following,

```
renames_dfs = []
for df in dfs:
    renames_dfs.append(df.rename(columns={'var1':'Foo','var2':'Hoo'},inplace = True))
```

This returns an empty list of `None`.  What mistake am I making here when i rename column names?

Comment: Only remove `inplace = True`, it return `None`

Comment: Perfect! It worked!

Comment: Or, `df.columns = ['Foo', 'Hoo']`

Comment: Shouldn't i have to have `inplace = True` according to the link I have?

Comment: @i.n.n.m You can bypass that by directly assigning to the columns. `inplace` will update the reference.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ that worked too, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your existing code returns `None` because `inplace=True` updates the reference inplace.

One efficient solution is to just assign to `df.columns` directly:

```
for df in dfs:
    df.columns = ['foo', 'bar']
```

Will update all dataframes in the same list without having to create a new list.

---

Another option is using `set_axis`, if you are renaming all the columns:

```
df2 = [df.columns.set_axis(['foo', 'bar'], axis=1, inplace=False) for df in dfs]
```

If renaming only a subset, use `rename` instead.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like this.

```
[df.rename(columns={'var1':'Foo','var2':'Hoo'},inplace=True) for df in dfs]
```

Output:

```
[None,None]
```

***BUT....***

```
dfs
```

Output:

```
[        Foo       Hoo
 0  0.463904  0.765987
 1  0.473314  0.609793
 2  0.505549  0.449539
 3  0.508157  0.444993
 4  0.604366  0.368044,         Foo       Hoo
 0  0.241526  0.225990
 1  0.609949  0.454891
 2  0.523094  0.443431
 3  0.525026  0.714601
 4  0.002260  0.763454]
```

Comment: Nooo.... don't use a list comprehension to create side effects. It's an anti pattern.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ, whould you mind to explain about those "side effects"?

Comment: @MaxU Basically the sole purpose of the list comp here is to do something besides composing the list. The actual contents of the list are discarded but the actions that are taken to create it have an effect on something else -- side effect.

Comment: @MaxU Just saying it isn't something you'd usually want to do. It isn't very idiomatic to begin with. Guess that's just my opinion though :)

Answer (score 1):

Parameter `inplace=True` always return `None`.

So you can use:

```
renames_dfs = []
for df in dfs:
    df.rename(columns={'var1':'Foo','var2':'Hoo'},inplace = True)
    renames_dfs.append(df)
```

But I think better:

```
renames_dfs = []
for df in dfs:
    renames_dfs.append(df.rename(columns={'var1':'Foo','var2':'Hoo'}))
```